# transform3d destroys effect with mix-blend-mode

Tags: css, mix-blend-mode

I created an effect with `mix-blend-mode`, which changes the text color from black to white when it moves in and outside of an image. But when I try to add an `transform3d` the effect disappears. How can I fix this?

https://codepen.io/faragos/pen/QWJVwmr

to see the effect the line

```
  transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
```

needs to be commented out.

I would expect `transform` should have no effect.

Comment: Transform creates a new stacking context.

Comment: Is there a way to get them together in the same stacking context again?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue today and the method that worked in my case was to move the `mix-blend-mode` higher up to the same level as the `transform`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).